# How do i do the following curl command in Java

Tags: java, url, curl, urlconnection

How would I implement the following curl command in Java URLConnection

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":73453}'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is curl command ?

Comment: curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":73453}' \

Comment: You can use http client api and [`setHeader()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html?is-external=true#setHeader%28org.apache.http.Header%29) method to set these headers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the derived class of [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) which is [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) you can easily do it.

```
URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
myURLConnection.connect();

JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("score", "73453");

OutputStream os = myURLConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));
os.close();
```

For  `curl -X GET \ -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \ -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " \ -G \ --data-urlencode 'include=game`

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
String query = String.format("include=%s", URLEncoder.encode("game", charset));
URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL+"?"+query);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "");
myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
myURLConnection.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I get the following Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/score/

Comment: @user3130151 my bad it's because i've put single quote instead of double. Tell me if it works now ?

Comment: @user3130151 just updated it again using JSONObjet and URLEncoder you will most likely not have 400 response code this time `:-)`

Comment: Khaled this is amazing :D