# How do I write the following APIGEE related curl command in Java?

Tags: java, curl, apigee

How do I write the following APIGEE related curl command in Java

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
https://{org-name}-test.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken? 
grant_type=client_credentials \
-d 'client_id={consumer-key}&client_secret={consumer-secret}'
```

Using curl is not allowed in our company so want to execute the command from Java. Any help would be appreciated.

Note - To some extent this URL was helpful [How do i do the following curl command in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110716/how-do-i-do-the-following-curl-command-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please post what you have tried and what you are thinking for your solution?  Otherwise this question is too broad to be answered.  To understand what makes a good question, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I tried the solution provided by the link "How do i do the following curl command in Java" but I could not go forward because of some the parameter used in the command for which I need help.

Comment: What error did you get from that solution?

Comment: Actually I'm not getting any error the problem is that I'm not able to map the command in Java code like other parameter so that I can run the program. Thanks for your response.